# codeigniter i get header already sent

Tags: codeigniter, model, controller

i got this error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header
>   information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/rapcomdk/public_html/system/language/danish/imglib_lang.php:1)
>   Filename: helpers/url_helper.php Line
>   Number: 541

i dont know what the problem is

here is my controller:

http://pastebin.com/EMtcMgsB

and here is my model file:

http://pastebin.com/iH6xQFGA

hope some one can help me out

Comment: try commenting the first two lines in your `index()` method, if the problem is gone, then it's either your model or the `$this->uri->segment(3)`.

Comment: it must be the function called "uploadImg" i have check all the orter thing it cold be

Comment: please copy and paste imglib_lang.php referenced in the error to pastebin.

Answer (score 3):

Check and make sure in `system/language/danish/imglib_lang.php` that you have no whitespace before the `<?php` tag and make sure you do not have a closing `?>` php tag in the file.

Comment: it dont have, and it works fine on my localhost mamp server but on my host it got that error :S

Comment: @Simon quite likely your FTP program adds some whitespace to the file during upload, often this happens. Try using a different FTP program or change the settings of your FTP program

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [jondavidjohn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702448/codeigniter-i-get-header-already-sent/4702458#4702458), if you're using Unicode encoding for the files, make sure there's not a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) starting off the file. On some platforms, this can wreak havoc on PHP processing.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there are no errors in codeigniter, sometimes the errors can be covered by other errors, such as one error lead to another.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `system/language/danish/imglib_lang.php`, which must have some character before the `<?php` part by the time it is parsed on the server. What's happening is that `helpers\url_helper.php` is trying to redirect (using this code;)

```
case 'refresh'  : header("Refresh:0;url=".$uri);
```

But is failing because `imglib_lang.php, line 1` has already sent some non-header text to the response. Since headers come first, it's giving you the warning.

I wonder at it working locally but not on the deployment server. It may be that the file is not being transferred cleanly, or that the servers use different versions of PHP with different handlings of character sets.

Several checks;

1. Be absolutely sure there is no BOM at the front of `system/language/danish/imglib_lang.php.` Let us know why you are certain. If you've edited the file in Notepad on windows, for instance, it'll have gained the Byte Order Mark. It can be very hard to tell since some tools 'swallow' the mark. Also make sure there's no plain whitespace.
2. When you save `imglib_lang.php`, make sure you save it in ASCII.
3. Compare local and remote versions of PHP. If there are differences, update your local copy to the same as the servers, and retest.
4. Check that the file is being transferred perfectly. If you are putting the file up using FTP, then FTP may be modifying it as it transfers it. FTP has two modes - an ASCII mode and a BINARY mode. If the files are being transferred as ASCII, then there may be some rewriting of the file going on. Try making sure `imglib_lang.php` is being transferred as BINARY to make sure the exact file is being uploaded.

Answer (score -1):

If you think that you have everything configured correctly, maybe your library (or specifically, `imglib_lang.php`) is simply producing PHP warnings or notices.  If you can get a hold of your logs from your host, it would be helpful.

Otherwise, you can try to turn off PHP's error reporting:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

(you can place that line in your index.php)